# How to check the location of the threat detected by Sophos on macOS?

Tags: macos, sophos

I'm using Sophos Home on macOS Sierra and I've given the following message after restart:

> Threat detected by Sophos
>
> 'Virus/Spyware' **Troj/JSDldr-EZ** has been detected.
> Cleanup will be performed automatically.

I'd like to know where exactly this threat has been detected (which file). How I can do that?

---

Here is my main window of Sophos Home app:

[image: Sophos Home on macOS Sierra, window]

Answer (score 0):

If you check Custom Scans and the Settings icon - you should be able to view the log files, maybe the files infected are listed in there.

Comment: On Mac I don't see any options for custom scan. I've attached the screenshot.